# Navigating push notification will close intermediate activity when back press navigated activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-pendingintent

I'm navigating to activity C when clicking push notification. Where activity A is my home screen and I'm currently in activity B from activity A while receiving a push notification. Consider now I'm receiving a push notification and clicking the received notification. After clicking push notification activity C gets loaded. Then I'm back pressing in my app this will close the intermediate activity B. But I do not want to close my intermediate activity.

My Pending intent for activity A looks like below,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, A.class);
     intent.putExtra(PUSH_MESSAGE, notification);
     PendingIntent.getActivity(context, previousId + 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and the manifest file looks like below,

```
<activity
        android:name=".A"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light.NoActionBar"/>
<activity
        android:name=".B"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light.NoActionBar" />
<activity
        android:name=".C"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Overlay"/>
```

Also i'm launching activity B from activity A like below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), B.class);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

and launching Activity C while clicking received push notification like below,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, C.class);
 intent.putExtra(C.IS_FROM_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true);
 ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_REFRESH);
```

Could you Please suggest me any idea to do this?

Comment: Please explain how you are launching C with `startActivityForResult()` from a push notification. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: How is A launched (using `PendingIntent`)? What launches A?

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:parentActivityName=".B"
        android:name=".C"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Overlay"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not only having B as an intermediate activity. I'm having n number of intermediate activity like B. I think i could not use like this.